# Remove the :hover event on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have the `:hover` event working on a website, but I have a problem when you use the system on mobile devices.

Is there a way to remove it in css or js? I have tried so many things but I have no luck.

I tried modernizr.com and media queries with no success.

**my sass code:**

```
ul {
    li {
      padding: 20px;
       &:hover {
        background-color: $red;
        color: $black;
      }
    }
  }
```

**media query:**

```
@media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  ul {
    li {
      &:hover {
        color: inherit; 
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**sass mq variable:**

```
$screen-sm-min: 768px;
```

Comment: Though you have already tried media queries , still I will let you know it can be possible with it.Please share your code

Comment: I edit my question with the code.

Comment: Why don't you only apply the hover styles at the width you want, rather than applying them for all widths then attempting to undo them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use *CSS media queries for interaction features*: http://caniuse.com/css-media-interaction

You can use to only apply `:hover` styles where this feature is available

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
    .your-selector:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can detect touch capabilities via javascript, **but this is not advisable** and generally not necessary since now you can just do it via CSS, dynamically.

```js
/* add a class to <html> */
var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window;
document.documentElement.className += isTouch?' touch ':' no-touch ';
```

```css
/* only use hover when the no-touch class is present */
.no-touch {
    .your-selector:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

---

Using this last solution with your code:

```
ul {
  li {
    padding: 20px;
     .no-touch &:hover {
      background-color: $red;
      color: $black;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've learned something new - thanks. Never used media queries for interaction features - I will be from now on!

Comment: What will happen if I'm using my laptop which have a touch screen and a mouse?